# Firefox crashing at startup

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

When trying to start Firefox in Lubuntu I get Mozilla Crash Reporter. I have also tried the following from the terminal.  What I need is to be able to open firefox without getting Mozilla Crash Reporter.

```
$ sudo firefox
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 5452
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...

$ firefox -safe-mode
Failed to open curl lib from binary, use libcurl.so instead
(crashreporter:5454): Gdk-WARNING **: crashreporter: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :1.0.
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 5693
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...

$ sudo apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 53.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 53.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 53.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

[image: Firefox Fault Screenshot]

[Firefox Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCeUX.jpg)

Comment: what if you run it from terminal?

Comment: If I use terminal, exactly the same thing happens plus a message Fatal 10 Error 11. I tried using a live CD with Lubuntu 16.04. Firefox works OK using this.

Comment: Try this: close firefox; run: `mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla-bk`; open firefox see what happens.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do this. I get the same message from Firefox.

Comment: Firefox works now or it crash again?

Comment: Still crashing.

Comment: I'm not sure what may be cause of the problem, I thought it might be some add-on, etc. seems that it's not.

Comment: No Danish Khan I have not fixed it. I installed ubuntu's own web browser (Browser) but that will not work either. It seems something in my set up is preventing web browsers from working. Is there some easy way of re installing Lubuntu 16.04 without me loosing all the changes I have made to make it work as I want? It took me weeks to get my print server to work.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy firefox` and `firefox -safe-mode`? Thanks.

Comment: I believe I had included  the output of apt-cache policy firefox and firefox -safe-mode to my question now.

Comment: @Marty Textual output is better than an image. Please use copy paste to give the output

Comment: It's look like a bug. Check the link here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/951429

Comment: @Anwar: That bug report is old as dirt. What makes you think it's about the same one?